# Update another user profile property in SharePoint 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service

I tried to implement it by referencing user profiles .asmx web service. So I call ModifyUserPropertyByAccountName method, but always receive "Operation Failure ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." if I try to update someone's (not mine) account. The query is executed by user, which is a member of Global Administrators. Tried to update another user profile via UI and was successful.

Any ideas on how to work it out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the ASMX, but all other remote interfaces, CSOM, JSOM, and REST are not allowed to alter a user profile (with the exception of the urser PhotoURL). I suspect that you will not be successful.

Matt

Comment: Thank you, Matt! I knew about client object model limitation, just thought that .asmx must be a win-win solution...